# SyntaxError: invalid syntax using pipes.quote

Tags: python-2.7, raspberry-pi3

Trying to create a shell script on a raspi3 in python to start a webcam. Getting a syntax error when trying to run the script.

Keep in mind I am new to Python but I have tried each individually to see what prints out, only getting this when I combine the script..

```py
from gpiozero import Button
from pipes import quote
import time
import os

print("your script has started")

camOutput = 'output_http.so -w ./www'
camInput = 'input_raspicam.so -hf'
camStart = '/home/pi/projects/mjpg-streamer/mjpg_streamer -o'.format(quote(camOutput)).'-i'.format(quote(camInput))

print("your script is loaded")

stopButton = Button(26) #shutdown
camButton = Button(25)  #web cam
ledButton = Button(24)  #top led

while True:
        if stopButton.is_pressed:
                time.sleep(1)
        if stopButton.is_pressed:
                os.system("shutdown now -h")
        time.sleep(1)
```

````
    camStart = '/home/pi/projects/mjpg-streamer/mjpg_streamer -o'.format(quote(camOutput)).'-i'.format(quote(camInput))
                                                                                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python, the dot operator is not used to concatenate strings, only to access properties and methods of an object.  Thus, putting a string literal after a dot, such as `.'-i'`, is a syntax error.

You probably want to do something like this, using the `format` method to replace the `{}` placeholders with the provided values:

```
camStart = '/..../mjpg_streamer -o {} -i {}'.format(quote(camOutput),quote(camInput))
```